# How to manage dependencies with ArgoCD?

Tags: argocd

How can I manage dependencies of my pods when deploying with ArgoCD?

**Why do I need this?**

I want to make sure, that first pod A is deployed and running successfully before pod B is deployed.

Flux offers such a [workload dependency feature](https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/kustomize/kustomization/#kustomization-dependencies). But I can't see such feature for ArgoCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy your pods in a given order by using **Sync Waves**.

**Example**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: podA
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "1"
...
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: podB
  annotations:
    argocd.argoproj.io/sync-wave: "2"
...
```

**Update: Waves for different applications**

If you want to have waves for different applications, than you need to patch the ArgoCD configuration: https://codefresh.io/blog/argo-cd-application-dependencies/

```
$ cat patch-argocd-cm.yaml

data:
  resource.customizations.health.argoproj.io_Application: |
    hs = {}
    hs.status = "Progressing"
    hs.message = ""
    if obj.status ~= nil then
      if obj.status.health ~= nil then
        hs.status = obj.status.health.status
        if obj.status.health.message ~= nil then
          hs.message = obj.status.health.message
        end
      end
    end
    return hs

$ kubectl patch cm/argocd-cm --type=merge -n argocd --patch-file patch-argocd-cm.yaml
```

**Documentation**
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/

Comment: But what can we do if these manifests are situated in different Applications? I've tested that podB won't wait for podA.

Comment: looks like the sync wave doesn't work if we use the applicationsets

Comment: @donRumatta Your question is, what happens if the Deployment are defined in separate files? Than also the podB waits for podA.
For me it doesn't matter, if you use a single file or multiple files.

Comment: @MatthiasM, I put first manifest for application, that creates custom resources for crossplane (sync-wave = 1), and others for application controlled by applicationset (sync-wave = 2). And second application doesn't wait for first one. Had to add some logic to wait for db creation.

Comment: @donRumatta  I've updated my answer for how to use waves with different applications.